# How to pull json data using POST method from http://www.infogroup.com/ API in VBA

Tags: api, excel, post, vba

I am trying to pull data from Infogroup API, I was able to pull data through a GET query but unable to pull data which required POST method. In the Infogroup API Console [http://developer.infoconnect.com/api-console][1] I am giving parameter as apikey = 4iRztNp5euNzjK3i69xlnpIMa3K6AZCv and in the body I am giving the following code:

```
{"Fields":
   ["Id",
   "Companyname",
   "Assets",
   "BankAsset",
   "BigBusinessSegmentation",
   "BusinessStatus",
   "CallStatus",
   "CompanyDescription",
   "CompDate",
   "CreditCardsAccepted",
   "CreditLimit",
   "FortuneRanking",
   "HoldingStatus",
   "InWealthyArea",
   "IsActiveWebAddress",
   "IsHomeBusiness",
   "IsFranchise",
   "Population",
   "ProductsSold",
   "StockExchange",
   "SquareFootage",
   "Subsidiary",
   "TeleResearchUpdateDate",
   "YearEstablished",
    "RecordStatus", 
    "Location"],
 "CompanyName":"DORAN MECHANICAL"
}
```

It is working fine in the console but I want to pull this data in Excel. Please help!

```
Function Post(CompName As String) As String
Dim companyname As String
Dim strQuery As String
Dim googleService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim rspText As String

companyname = URLEncode(CompName)

strQuery = "https://api.infoconnect.com/v1/companies/search?apikey=4iRztNp5euNzjK3i69xlnpIMa3K6AZCv"


googleService.Open "POST", strQuery, False
googleService.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
googleService.setRequestBody "Fields": ["Id","Companyname","Assets","BigBusinessSegmentation","CreditRatingScore", "Location"] , "companyname": CompName

rspText = googleService.responseText

Creditrating = "NA"

If InStr(1, rspText, """CreditRatingScore"":""") Then
    Creditrating = Split(Split(rspText, """CreditRatingScore"":""")(1), Chr(34))(0)
End If
End Function
```

Comment: post your POST code :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Posted the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the setRequestBody in your code is not valid json, which code be causing your error. As far as the display fields, casing is important (e.g. your code uses Companyname where it should be CompanyName) and from my testing it doesn't always return values for the requested fields (e.g. didn't return Assets for "Doran Mechanical").

Valid body (Note: surrounded in `{` and `}` for JSON object and keys and values strings are quoted `""`):

```
"{""CompanyName"":""" & CompanyName & """,""Fields"":[""Id"",""CompanyName"",...]}"
```

Here's an example of using [VBA-Web](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web) for this request:

```
Function CreditRating(CompanyName As String) As Dictionary
    Dim Client As New WebClient
    Client.BaseUrl = "https://api.infoconnect.com/v1"

    Dim Request As New WebRequest
    Request.Resource = "companies/search"
    Request.Method = WebMethod.HttpPost
    Request.Format = WebFormat.Json
    Request.AddQuerystringParam "apikey", "4iRz..."
    Request.AddBodyParameter "CompanyName", CompanyName
    Request.AddBodyParameter "Fields", Array("Id", "CompanyName", "CreditRatingScore", "Assets", "BankAsset", "BigBusinessSegmentation", "BusinessStatus")

    Dim Response As WebResponse
    Set Response = Client.Execute(Request)

    ' Example Response:
    ' [{"ETag":"...","Id":"...","Links":[...],"CompanyName":"Doran Mechanical",...,"CreditRatingScore":"B"}]
    ' (JSON Array of Objects -> Collection, 1-based of Dictionary -> Return first Dictionary
    CreditRating = Response.Data(1)("CreditRatingScore")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)  However it is showing Compiler error : "user-defined type not defined".   Is there any additional reference which I am missing over here or is it because of something else?